# Couldn't match expected type with actual type

Tags: haskell

I've recently started learning Haskell and is having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my code but ended up in failure.

This is part of my code showing that I've declared data Constructor for Graph type, which is a list of tuple of a value and a list of that value.

```
data Graph a = Graph [(a,[a])] deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)
```

This is type synonym for tuple of two ints,

```
type Point = (Int, Int)
```

And finally this code is to find second argument of a graph using first argument(i.e searching / hashing value)

```
pointNeighbor :: Graph Point -> Point -> [Point]
pointNeighbor (x:xs) point = if fst x == point then snd x else pointNeighbor (xs) point
```

This is the error message I get when I try to load module

> hw1.hs:37:16:
>       Couldn't match expected type ‘Graph Point’
>                   with actual type ‘[(Point, [Point])]’
>       In the pattern: x : xs
>       In an equation for ‘pointNeighbor’:
>           pointNeighbor (x : xs) point
>             = if fst x == point then snd x else pointNeighbor (xs) point
>
> hw1.hs:37:79:
>       Couldn't match expected type ‘Graph Point’
>                   with actual type ‘[(Point, [Point])]’
>       In the first argument of ‘pointNeighbor’, namely ‘(xs)’
>       In the expression: pointNeighbor (xs) point

It seems like Graph Point should be recognized as [(Point,[Point])] but apparently it is giving me this error and I can't find any solution on web.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function expects the first argument to be of type `Graph`. As `Graph` is defined, there is only one way to do this: with the `Graph` value constructor (the ocurrence of the word `'Graph'` on the *right hand side* of the `=` in the `data` definition).

However, the pattern match you are trying to perform pretends like the first argument is plain `List`, instead of a `List` that has been made part of the `Graph` value constructor.

The pattern match should be for `(Graph (x:xs))` and also the recursive call in the `else` clause should use `(Graph xs)` like this:

```
pointNeighbor :: Graph Point -> Point -> [Point]
pointNeighbor (Graph (x:xs)) point = 
    if fst x == point 
        then snd x 
        else pointNeighbor (Graph xs) point
```

Note also that you don't define a base case when the list is empty.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it better now :) I've also noticed that I should fix (xs) part to (Graph (xs)) too.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Graph` is a data constructor, you have to pattern match against it:

```
pointNeighbor :: Graph Point -> Point -> [Point]
pointNeighbor (Graph (x:xs)) point = if fst x == point then snd x else pointNeighbor (Graph xs) point
               ^^^^^                                                                  ^^^^^
```

Comment: I just realized that my solution, like yours, needs another use of `Graph` around the recursive call to `pointNeighbor` in the `else` clause ... `(Graph xs)` or the recursive call will suffer the same fate as the OP's original.